# Create job from Dataflow template from Go app

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to launch a Dataflow job from an existing template, via a Go app.

So far, I've brought in `google.golang.org/api/dataflow/v1b3` and created a `CreateJobFromTemplateRequest` with the job info.

How can I now execute that request using the built-in service account credentials in Compute Engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Auto-generated Google APIs for Go](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/) is only recommended if there is a [Google Client Library for Go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go) developed for the service you are calling. There is not a client library yet for Dataflow.

To launch a Dataflow template from a Go app using default credentials:

```
ctx := context.Background()
oauthClient, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, dataflow.CloudPlatformScope)

dataflowService, err := dataflow.New(oauthClient)

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

templateRequest := dataflow.CreateJobFromTemplateRequest{
  GcsPath: "gcs path to template here",
  JobName: "choose a unique job name here",
  Parameters: map[string]string{
    "parameters": "for job",
  },
}

result, err := dataflowService.Projects.Templates.Create("project id", &templateRequest).Do()

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```